# Is it possible to set up multistore in Woocommerce?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, multisite, e-commerce, woocommerce-offtopic

Is it possible to have a multistore in WooCommerce?

I want to divide my [WooCommerce](https://woocommerce.com/) store into 3 distinct stores with the toys showing up in 3 different collection names called:

- remote cars
- robots
- funny

Is it possible to set up up 3 different stores or collections using WooCommerce? Or do I need to go for [Magento](https://magento.com/)?

Comment: I would suggest you to use the Mrinvent platform. The problem with having multiple installations is that it won't sync your stock. So if you sell a product in one store, you will have to change the stock in your other installations as well. Mrinvent solves all of these problems.

https://mrinvent.online/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Woocommerce is a plugin for wordpress and cannot run multiple stores. However you may want to run wordpress as a multisite installation and for each site, you install plugin and can control all three stores from one wordpress admin.
However i will recommend Magento, as its capable of multi store.
 Hope it helps

Comment: so you meant to say i have to create multisite first and then install woocommerce for each store . i can not manage my products from main network site.

Comment: As a super admin you can do anything you like.

Comment: it means i can create different categories for different site and assign different products to different site. in short i can keep different site data at one place am i right?

Comment: @JackTorris Under mutlisite installtion, you can keep supervise all 3 sites under one admin.

Comment: Perhaps this may help:

While you can network activate plugins, like WooCommerce and it's extensions, you wouldn't be able to share product databases, checkout, user accounts, etc... across the sites in the network at this time.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27745555/woocommerce-global-product-multisite

Comment: Actually, you can now accomplish this very thing with the WooCommerce MultiStore plugin: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40023541/3254362

Answer (score 2):

You could Network enable the WooCommerce plugin and use it on multiple sub sites however you could also create multiple product categories and use one site which may be a better solution and one which is easier to manage.

Comment: hi , thanks for reply.  i am really confuse now. does it mean i could mange the products from one main site. can i select which product would display in which site?